# Any way to characterize this family of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion, recursion, lambert-w

I have a family of polynomials generated by the recurrence relation

$P_{n+1}(w) = (1+w)P_n ^{\ \prime}(w) -(3n-1 +nw)P_n(w) \\ P_1(w) =1$

The family is related to the Lambert $W$-function by its Taylor series expansion around $x=e$

$$W_0(x) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty { P_n(1) \over 2^{2n-1}e^n } (x-e)^n$$

Is there any easier way to generate this polynomial family, than this recurrence relation? Or perhaps an explicit function, $P_n(w) = F(n,w)$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: [This](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~rpschne/W(x)andBell.pdf) may be relevant.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis : ithe Bell polynomials satisfy a different reccurence relation ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Recurrence_relations

Comment: could you write what you get when writing the recurrence relation for the coefs of the polynomials ?

Comment: Is this a trick question?  Of course recursion is the easiest way to generate the family.  Learn to love recursion!